# Setting to improve Visual Studio inscrutable compile/build error: MSB6006: "CL.exe" exit code 2

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I recently (finally!) upgraded to VS2019 from VS2008 and I ran across a ridiculous error that I had never seen before - MSB6006: "CL.exe" exit code 2.

After some searching, Microsoft suggested a screwed up Path variable. Nope! 
And then a lot of other people on the interweb had the same error for screwy and seemingly unrelated reasons.

I finally found the problem by disabling sections of my code one-at-a-time.  It turned out I forgot to return a value in a non-void function.

It was something like this:

```
class myClass{
    int classMember;
....
    int memberFunc(int input){
        int out = input * classMember;
        //should have returned 'out' here but I didn't.
    }
};
```

My two questions are:

1) What in the HOLY **** happened to the nice, user friendly compiler error in VS2008 that used to tell me I had forgotten to return a value?  (not that -ahem- I do that very often.)

2) Is there a way to get the nice error message back?  Some setting buried somewhere?  Perhaps even some sort of default configuration VS2019 is using for my projects that I can dumb-down?

And next, here's a thought for any others who are beating their heads against the MSB6006 wall:  The fact that I got this opaque build error when VS2019 SHOULD have caught a very simple and explainable compile-time error implies that others may be seeing it for similar reasons - that is, something simple that you would normally expect the compiler to catch for you isn't being caught...  Systematically disabling sections of code worked for me.

Comment: It's a compiler bug. Don't like compiler bugs? No problem! Just get a bug free compiler.

Comment: In VS2019, I'd guess you need to look into settings related to "C++ Core Guidelines warnings" within the IDE.    Incidentally, most compilers treat warning about falling off the end of a function as a discretionary warning, that is disabled by default  (i.e. if you want that warning, you need to specifically enable it).   All sorts of history behind that - but ultimately developers lobbied compiler vendors to do it that way, and made their own nest.

Comment: Your code causes a "error C4716: 'myClass::memberFunc': must return a value" diagnostic on my VS2019 desktop and on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/VvyrPd). You might try repairing your Visual Studio installation.